# Broadcast a column to all rows using Trigger Function on Update

Tags: postgresql

I have a table:

| uid | history | updatedAt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | someOlderJson | 2022-12-31:23:59:59 |
| b | someNewerJson | 2023-01-01:00:00:30 |

And I would like to update the table to the below state when the history column is updated to `someNewestJson`:

| uid | history | updatedAt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | someNewestJson | 2023-01-02:00:00:30 |
| b | someNewestJson | 2023-01-02:00:00:30 |

Is there a way to do this in postgresql?

P/S: I only have access to the DB and would like the update to be automatically perform anytime the column is updated.

Comment: All I am seeing changing is  the `history` column value so why not just do: `update the_table set history = 'someNewestJson';`? No trigger needed.

Comment: I only have access to the database. So the purpose for the trigger is to perform the update query for me automatically.

Comment: Still not seeing what you are trying to achieve? What is the purpose of updating all the `history` values to a single value?

Comment: My purpose is to let all users share the same history. When user A creates a new post, user B also could see it. However the original design of the software does not do that.

Comment: Not seeing it, as the `updatedAt` does not change. Also why should change user B data change for something user A did?

Comment: My bad, `updatedAt` should be updated. This is a collaborative note service, to have more ease of access, when User A creates a note, User B could directly access it. And user A doesn't need to share the link to every user so they could end up with the same "history". BTW, "history" shows the notes that a user has opened, since I the users are all in the same team, there is no "privacy concerns" in terms of notes created.